# Exchange occurrences of character

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the most optimized way to exchange occurrences of all characters. So, what I want to basically accomplish is to replace all double quote characters by single quote and all single quote by double quote characters.

The topmost idea on my head would include 3 steps. In simple words, I would replace *a* by *c* then *b* by *a* and then *a* by *b*. However, I don't think so that this would be a good approach.

So, the question is, what would be the best approach here?

Comment: More detail required here, are you looking to do this in the text of your site or its code? 1 specific element or all of them?

Comment: Trying using some unique characters instead of a, b or c. Your idea sounds ok to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about a regex with a callback

```
str.replace(/('|")/g, function(x) {
    return x=='"' ? "'" : '"';
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/aLgx6/)

Comment: Excellent answer bro. Saved a day of effort. That's y I love stackoverflow. Superb.>! Thumbs up!! (FYI: I will soon update the reason for the question; once I am sure about the problem). Thanks again.! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is actually the most optimal. In javascript, it's just one line:

```
 x.replace(/'/g, '\x01').replace(/"/g, "'").replace(/\x01/g, '"')
```

More flexible, although [slower](http://jsperf.com/3repl-vs-callback) would be a callback function:

```
replacements = { '"': "'", "'": '"' etc }

x.replace(/['"]/g, function($m) { return replacements[$m] })
```

http://jsperf.com/3repl-vs-callback

Comment: I guess wether or not a callback is slower than parsing the string three times depends ?

Comment: @adeneo: I created a jsperf for this.

Comment: Ah, I am sorry, I missed this..Let me go through this too..!..Thanks>!

Comment: Excellent. You are right, this is indeed a faster option compared to the callback option. I would like to accept both the answers if there was an option..! Thumbs up.>!